# best approach for file structure?

Tags: performance, file-structure

What is better / faster?
We need a short and fast file structure for a javascript / ajax web app

rs -> c (for css files)
rs -> j (for js files)
rs -> i (for images)

or:

-> stylesheets
-> scripts
-> images

or:

-> css
-> js
-> img

does it make any difference if the urls are shorter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about two or three bytes in your source code per resource (pre-compression). Then either your website is already highly optimised or you're looking in the wrong place for performance gains.

I'd be more concerned with how your content delivery is spread across things like subdomains/CDNs to maximise load throughput.

Ensure everything is cacheable, also things like ensuring your script includes are bunched up if you can and includes in your CSS.

Comment: so using client side storage and json combined with cookies for caching requests would improve the performance much more

Comment: AJAX will decrease the need for full page loads. Your images, CSS and JavaScript should be cached as long as your webserver is set up correctly. If you use multiple subdomains for delivery of your payload or a CDN then you'll find that you'll maximise the amount of parallel loading you can do.

Answer (score 0):

The folder names make no difference. You should focus on actually optimizing your files and how they are delivered.

Once you have optimized your files, consider looking into a content delivery networking like [www.cloudflare.com](http://www.cloudflare.com/) if you are worried about speed.